# How to rename only files which are common with ones in another directory using batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

there are two directories which have some common files, e.g.

```
c:\1\a.exe
c:\1\k.exe
```

and

```
c:\2\a.exe
c:\2\b.exe
c:\2\k.exe
```

In the second directory, I would like to renames files which are common with first one, how can i do that?

In fact, i want to iterate over first directory and rename the same files in the second directory.

so eventually I want the file sin second directory to be

```
c:\2\ZZa.exe
c:\2\b.exe
c:\2\ZZk.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distill this into a single line of code - you can test this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\1\*") do if exist "c:\2\%%~nxa" ren "c:\2\%%~nxa" "ZZ%%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
@echo off

setlocal


set "firstDir=c:\1"
set "secondDir=c:\2"

for %%# in ("%firstDir%") do set "firstDir=%%~f#"
for %%# in ("%secondDir%") do set "secondDir=%%~f#"

for %%# in ("%secondDir%*") do (
   if exist "%firstDir%\%%~nx#" do (
     ren "%secondDir%\%%~nx#" "ZZ%%~nx#"
  )
)
endlocal
```